# How to teach google test to print types from std?

Tags: c++, googletest, c++03, googlemock

I have a test where I need to print out `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` but even though that I declare and define an operator for that googletest will comlain that it cannot find it.

Having [google test manual mention](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#teaching-googletest-how-to-print-your-values) that

```
// It's important that the << operator is defined in the SAME
// namespace that defines Bar.  C++'s look-up rules rely on that.
```

Should I reopen `std` namespace and place my `operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& p)` there?

Excerpt from code:

```
// included from somewhere else in legacy code:
// typedef ::std::map< ::std::string, ::std::string > AttrList;
bool UserDefinedTypeMatcher::MatchAndExplain(UserDefinedType& r, testing::MatchResultListener* listener) const {
  typedef AttrList::const_iterator AttrIt;
  std::pair<AttrIt, AttrIt> pattr = std::mismatch(r.attr.begin(), r.attr.end(), expectedUserDefinedType.attr.begin());
  if(pattr.first != r.attr.end() && pattr.second != expectedUserDefinedType.attr.end())
  {
    *listener << "\nFail: attr members differ on the following elements: "
        << "from given UserDefinedType: " << *pattr.first << '\n'
        << ", from expected UserDefinedType : " << *pattr.second << '\n';
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Compiler error:

```
/opt/gmock-1.7.0/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h: In member function ‘testing::MatchResultListener& testing::MatchResultListener::operator<<(const T&) [with T = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’:
test/src/matchers/UserDefinedTypeMatchers.cpp:50:   instantiated from here
/opt/gmock-1.7.0/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:93: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘*(std::ostream*)((testing::MatchResultListener*)this)->testing::MatchResultListener::stream_ << x’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:108: note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:117: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:127: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:165: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:169: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:173: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ostream.tcc:91: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:180: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ostream.tcc:105: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:191: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:200: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:204: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:209: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:213: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:221: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:225: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ostream.tcc:119: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/opt/gmock-1.7.0/gtest/include/gtest/gtest-message.h:232: note:                 std::ostream& testing::operator<<(std::ostream&, const testing::Message&)
/opt/gmock-1.7.0/gtest/include/gtest/gtest-test-part.h:120: note:                 std::ostream& testing::operator<<(std::ostream&, const testing::TestPartResult&)
```

**EDIT**:

Ok, so I've learned that I can do the following:

```
bool UserDefinedTypeMatcher::MatchAndExplain(UserDefinedType& r, testing::MatchResultListener* listener) const {
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> mypair;
    // use and manipulate mypair
    *listener << ::testing::PrintToString(mypair);
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you make a type alias with the `using` keyword inside a namespace and place the operator there?

Comment: Can you share a piece of code what so you mean exactly?

Comment: `namespace foo { using mytype = std::pair<...>; [insert operator << here] }`
Does that help ? :)

Comment: I would just reopen the `std` namespace. It is not officially supported, but if there is no matching `operator<<`, it's going to work. Just keep in mind that it might get defined some day and then you'll have to conditionally undefine it.

Comment: For GoogleTest - just define function PrintTo - see https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#teaching-google-test-how-to-print-your-values  . Then it should automatically work PrintToString (as you found by yourself). Happily to you - most of std stuff already have PrintTo

Comment: @PiotrNycz I've tried both defining `operator<<` and `PrintTo` and none of them work. I needed to add e.g. `operator<<` in reopened `namespace std` to make it work but in the end I decided to go for `::testing::PrintToString`

Comment: @Patryk open gtest-printers.h from gtest  and learn how they managed to write PrintTo for pair

Comment: Just use a struct of your own instead if possible.